# selecting a day from UICalendar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-click, ui-calendar

I am fairly new to angular I am trying to implement a calendar using ui-calendar. So far I have been able to display a very basic calendar and some events on it.

Now I need to be able to click on a day and display the detailed events on a side tab. I seem to be lost on how to achieve this clicking day thing. This may seems very naive, I thought i'd find the html for each day cell on the calendar, and then it would be as easy as attaching a ng-click to it. But I cant seem to find any template where the html for calendar is. All I can see is the directive, which doesnt help much. I dont understand jquery at all, so I am really struggling to find any answers too.

To sum things up, I just want to know how to make a day on calendar clickable.

Thanks in advance.

**code:**

```
$scope.uiConfig = {
  calendar: {
    height: 450,
    editable: true,
    header: {
      left: 'title',
      center: '',
      right: 'today prev,next'
    },
    eventClick: $scope.alertOnEventClick,
    eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
    eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize,
    eventRender: $scope.eventRender,
    dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
      console.log("inside dayClick");
      alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());
      var events = myCalendar.fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(event) {
        return event.start.isSame(date) || event.end.isSame(date) || date.isBetween(event.start, event.end); // Will return all events starting/ending on this date or overlapping this date
      });
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: when you mention ui-calendar...are you using FullCalendar or UIDatepicker ?

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far

Comment: @ Nikhil Nanjappa, by the ui-calendar, i mean the fullcalendar directive implementation of angularjs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your configuration variable you can add a [`dayClick`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/dayClick/) callback , in this callback you can do something like this:

```
dayClick: function( date, jsEvent, view ) { 
    var events = myCalendar.fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(event) {
        return event.start.isSame(date) || event.end.isSame(date) || date.isBetween(event.start, event.end); // Will return all events starting/ending on this date or overlapping this date
    });
}
```

This will return all the events that either are on this day or overlap it.

FullCalendar docs can be found [here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/).

Comment: thanks for the response. I was able to get an alert when the callback is fired. can you kindly elaborate what myCalendar is in the code snippet you presented above.

Comment: Your FullCalendar element, it's in uiCalendarConfig I think

Comment: is it the one named  calendar="myCalendar"  inside the directive. it throws an error. myCalendar is not defined

Comment: You did <div ui-calendar="myCalendar"> somewhere in your template, you can access your calendar in your controller with whatever you've entered in `ui-calendar` (so $scope.myCalendar) in this case

Comment: you need to add `calendar="myCalendar"` in your html code and add `uiCalendarConfig` as service in your controller: `angular.module('mymodule').controller('myController, ['uiCalendarConfig', ...` then you can access the myCalendar via `uiCalendarConfig.calendars.myCalendar` and use it as Martijn suggested.

Comment: Thanks Martijn Welker and Develman, with your help I was able to get it working.